# UML class diagram when templated forms are involved

Tags: class, uml, diagram, generalization

I'm learning UML diagramming and I am bit confused how to draw the class diagram for my problem

- A Firm has many users
- A User can belong to many firms
- A Firm has many templated forms
- A User can't create their own forms but can clone and use a Firm's templated forms

My questions:

- It this UML diagram right?
- Is `Form` split into 2 classes or is that unnecessary?
- Or is there a better way of doing this?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This diagram is not wrong.  I wonder however if there shouldn't be an association between the user form and the cloned template form.

There is an open question about whether a form template is also a form. Your short narrative seems to assume this.  Another alternative could be to not let inherit `FormTemplate` from `Form`, but to [prefer composition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composition_over_inheritance), by associating a `Form` to the `FormTemplate`.  The cloning of a user form would then clone only the form information of the template and not the metadata that is only relevant for the template.